# Angular and Firebase Async Problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am working on a pretty basic angular app right now to learn more about Angular and Firebase. I have it hosted via openshift at angular-jakeangularjs.rhcloud.com/ . I have it so that you can write data to it in real time using Firebase and such but for some reason the editing isnt working.

For example click on one of the "posts" headlines and that takes you to the edit view. For some reason the data isn't filling in like its supposed to. I know its getting the right data from the controller because if you wait 5 seconds you will get an alert with the data ( i put a js delay on it) it appears to be a problem with asynchronous loads.

I am passing the data that's in the alert to the scope but its just returning a null object. I'm guessing this needs to be a promise, but I am not to experienced with that part of async coding so was just wondering what is going wrong.

My controller is:

```
function projectCtrl($scope,$routeParams, Model,Projects,fbURL, $firebase) {
    var data = Projects;
    $scope.projects = Model.get($routeParams.projectid);
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(JSON.stringify(Model.get($routeParams.projectid)));
    }, 5000);
}
```

So it should be passing the data onto the scope object but it doesn't. However, it will alert me with the correct data after a 5 second delay.

Its hosted on github if you need to check out the code ( https://github.com/jakeboyles/AngularProject )

Comment: So... What is your question precisely?

Comment: Why isnt the data being loaded into the edit view?

Comment: Your edit link has an extra `/` - `#/projects//edit` - Is that why?

Comment: Sorry didnt mean edit. I mean just the single project view. So here is an example: http://angular-jakeangularjs.rhcloud.com/#/projects/-JItXKbKgZ6kEPE8pCSR

Comment: Please include a minimal code sample that reproduces your problem in the question. Without that, the question will be useless for future visitors, once you fix it on github. In general, questions that include a so-called SSCCE attract better answers faster.

Comment: Thanks. I added a code sample of my controller, that should help.

Comment: What does Model look like? That's the object that should be "passing it onto scope" right? We'd need to see that to make a guess I think. Check out [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)